# What it always returns 0

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to retrieve data with Hibernate with ID

this is my helper class:

```
public class ftHelper {

    Session session = null;

    public ftHelper(){
        this.session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    }

    public List getFtResult(String beginDate) {
    List<FinancialTransactions> ftList = null;
    try {
        org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Query q = session.createQuery ("from FinancialTransactions where Date='"+beginDate+"'");
        ftList = (List<FinancialTransactions>) q.list();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ftList;
}

    public FinancialTransactions getByID(){

        System.out.print("HERE");

       FinancialTransactions ft = null;

    try {

        org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Query q = session.createQuery("from FinancialTransactions where ID=" + 1);
        ft = new FinancialTransactions(1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ft;

    }
```

i use here getById function to retrieve data

I have a controller class

```
import javax.faces.model.DataModel;
import javax.faces.model.ListDataModel;

/**
 *
 * @author mert
 */
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class ftController {

    String beginDate;
    DataModel fts;
    ftHelper ft;
    int num;

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }



    /**
     * Creates a new instance of ftController
     */
    public ftController() {


    }

    public DataModel getFts() {

        if (fts == null) {
            fts = new ListDataModel(ft.getFtResult(beginDate));
        }
        return fts;
    }

    public int getID(){

        FinancialTransactions ftObject = ft.getByID();


        return num = ftObject.getAmount();

    }

}
```

in this controller i use getID function to get the object

In jsf i did like that:

But it always prints 0 why?

i think there is something wrong in my class because

i edited getID() function in my controller like that:

```
  public int getID(){
FinancialTransactions fta = new FinancialTransactions(5, "asdasdsa", 123);

        return num = fta.getAmount();
}
```

num also returns 0 why why why? What is the problem here?

Comment: What does your `FinancialTransactions` class look like?

Comment: If `id` is the primary key of your `FinancialTransactions` entity class, just do `session.get(FinancialTransactions.class, id)`. No query needed and no explicit transaction needed. You seem to be making things much more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You are not executing your query in the getByID()

```
public FinancialTransactions getByID(){

    System.out.print("HERE");

   FinancialTransactions ft = null;

try {

    org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    Query q = session.createQuery("from FinancialTransactions where ID=" + 1);

    // q.getResultList(); MISSING HERE
    ft = new FinancialTransactions(1);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```